# What's wrong in this python code?

Tags: python

```
def vector(sample_list):
    for item in sample_list:
        sums = 0
        square = item**2
        sums = square + sums

    magnitude = sums**0.5
    return magnitude

print(vector([2,3,-4]))
```

Why this code doesn't give the correct magnitude?
It gives the last value of the vector in function call.

Comment: Oh gee - a riddle. Whats wrong with your title ? Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) .

Comment: `sums` doesn't appear to do a good job of tracking the sum

Comment: Look where `sums = 0` is....

Comment: Two versions of python as tags. And django. What's the relevance?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change `sums=0` position

```
def vector(sample_list):
    sums = 0
    for item in sample_list:
        square = item**2
        sums = square + sums
    magnitude = sums**0.5
    return magnitude
```